# I am confused on purpose of using "Not", also on matching of "If" criteria, code says "is nothing" else run code for "MsgBox"

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Range(Target.Address))  _
    Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Working"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There isn't really a question being asked here but I'll guess that you're trying to understand the code. If so:

The conditional `If...then' says "if the range called "search_string" is not found in the target address' then a box should pop up to tell you that it's working

Comment: @RaphaelS, I believe it's the other way around: `If Not ... is Nothing Then`. =)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you mean you do not understand how the current code works? If yes, then I recommend reading about [Excel VBA Intersect Method](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/vba-intersect.htm), especially the section about `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: Lol @JvdV you're right it's a double negative (why?!)

Comment: That's to check if `Intersect` returns a valid `Range` object to work with @RaphaelS

Comment: use of not is confusing me and even on matching the criteria true returns is nothing

Comment: @user3094359 it might be the line continuation `_` that's confusing you. The `Is Nothing` is part of the `If ... Then`.  Read the formula as "If Not(the intersection of two ranges Is Nothing) Then". So it's saying "If two ranges have any cells in common Then Working"

Comment: And FWIW `Range(Target.Address))` is equivalent to just `Target`.  And the unqualified `Range` is better to be fully qualified.   In a Sheet module that's `If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: thanks all, now i understand, same as double negative These are all equivalent
***
If (Not (myobject Is Nothing) = True) Then *** and ***
If Not (myobject Is Nothing) Then *** and ***
If Not myobject Is Nothing Then *** thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Explanations are in the macro

```
'Change-event procedure for a specific sheet
'(The code is placed in the code module of this sheet)
'Always called when something changes in the sheet that triggers the change event
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  'We need the double negation in the following line because the answer of the
  'core question "Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Range(Target.Address))"
  'can have two different data types. An Object or the special type "Nothing"
  'if there is no object. There is no other way to ask for **no** address.
  'To ask only for an address will throw a runtime error if there is no one
  'But if it's "Not" "Nothing", then there is an address.
  'This is a bit hard to understand, but programming is like this sometimes ;-)
  If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    'Message field with the text "Working" is displayed
    'when the If statement is evaluated as "true"
    MsgBox "Working"
  End If
End Sub
```